# PHP Laravel Send Excel and PDF as attachment in email

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send both pdf and excel attachment in an email. Currently I am able to do so for pdf and I have no idea on how to do it for excel. Please help me.

```
//Controller
    public function sendEmail(Request $request){

        $bill = Bill::find(decrypt($request->id));
        ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');  

        $email=$bill->campus->email;

        $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($bill->billDate->start_date));
        $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($bill->billDate->end_date));
        $model = Models::where('sub_components','billgeneration')->first();
        $datas = array();
        $datas2 = array();
        $dotas = array();
        $dotas2 = array();
        $energy_target = 0;
        $energy_Actual = 0;
        $co2_target = 0;
        $co2_Actual = 0;
        $teo = 0;

        $curr_date_1 = date('Y-m-d 00:00', strtotime('+1 day'.$end_date));
        $curr_date_2 = date('Y-m-d 00:29', strtotime('+1 day'.$end_date));
        $prev_date_1 = date( 'Y-m-d 00:00', strtotime($start_date));
        $prev_date_2 = date( 'Y-m-d 00:29', strtotime($start_date));
        
        $smtmeters = DB::select("select a.id, a.serial_number,
        CONCAT(?,' to ',?) as curr_date, 
        CONCAT(?,' to ',?) as prev_date,
        (select b.acc_actual_generation from smt_meter_reading b 
        where b.smt_smart_meter_id=a.id
        and b.read_time between ? and ?) as ttl_1,
        (select b.acc_actual_generation from smt_meter_reading b 
        where b.smt_smart_meter_id=a.id
        and b.read_time between ? and ?) as ttl_2
        from smt_smart_meter a where a.campus_id = ? ;",[
            $curr_date_1,$curr_date_2,
            $prev_date_1,$prev_date_2,
            $curr_date_1,$curr_date_2,
            $prev_date_1,$prev_date_2,
            $bill->campus_id
        ]);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('billgeneration.exportPDFBill', compact('bill','smtmeters','energy_target','energy_Actual','co2_target','co2_Actual','teo'));
        $filename = $application->de_application_id . '-' . time() . '.xlsx';
        $message = new SendEmailBillGeneration($bill);
        $message->attachData($pdf->output(), "Bill Statement.pdf");
        try{
            Mail::to($email)->send($message);
            auditTrail('Send Email Approve','Billing','Bill Generation',$bill->id,$bill->bill_no,Auth::user()->users_id);
        }catch (\Exception $e){
            \Log::error($e);
            return response()->json([
                'message' => 'Cannot save data. Please contact your system administrator.'
            ],500);
        }

        return response()->json([
            'message' => 'Bill generation approval successfully sending!']);
    }
```

Above is the send email function in BillGenerationController. What I am trying to do, when the user click send email button, it will send email with a pdf and an excel attachment.

Comment: which laravel version you are using?

Comment: @PalakJadav I'm using Laravel ver 5.6.40